# How can I define a filled structure/table as class constant in ABAP Objects

Tags: oop, abap

I want to have an immutable predefined table as class variable. How do I define such a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, with a simple answer:
Just create a static method (getter) that returns constant data.

Instead of using:

```
data(ls_sample) = lcl_myclass=>cs_data.
```

Use:

```
data(ls_sample) = lcl_myclass=>cs_data( ).
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an attribute and mark it as "Read Only", You can set it via Constructor or with Set-Method.

Comment: if it has a set.method, is it unmutable?

Comment: A read-only attribute can be changed from within the class, so it is not true that it is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this using class constants in ABAP. The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_731_index_htm/7.31/en-US/abapconstants.htm) explicitly says that:

> - You can specify a start value val for the ABAP types string and
>   xstring only.
> - Constant internal tables, reference variables, and structures with not
>   purely character-like flat components **can be assigned their initial
>   value by IS INITIAL only, and are therefore always initial.**

As Tapio suggested, your only choice is read-only attributes, and I also suggest you to use static attributes, which can be initialized in constructor.

For example

```
CLASS lcl_test DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  CLASS-DATA: itab TYPE RANGE OF i READ-ONLY.
  METHODS:
      class_constructor.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_test IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD class_constructor.
      itab = VALUE #( sign = 'I'  option = 'BT' ( low = 1  high = 10 )
                                                ( low = 21 high = 30 )
                                                ( low = 41 high = 50 )
                                  option = 'GE' ( low = 61 )  ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: A read-only attribute can be changed from within the class, so it is not true that it is immutable.

Comment: BTW init your class-data read-only in class_constructor not constructor

Answer (score 0):

One thing that after all that time would be a workaroud is the following:

- Create your list
- serialize it and save it as a read-only string
- create a getter that deserializes it

Comment: "Save it as constant?" What do you mean by that?